# Count the number of times a specific input is present in an form

Tags: php

Is there a way to count how many times an `<input type="text" name="a">` appears in an form?

I have tried

```
$count = count($_POST['a']) ;
```

but this counts all inputs regardless the name of the input...

Comment: Are you saying that you have more than one `<input type="text" name="a">` in your form? Post the form please.

Comment: … also don't forget to use brackets: `<input type="text" name="a[]">` when dealing with multiple inputs with the same name.

Comment: yes... i have 4 of those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML forms shouldn't contain more than one `<input>` element with the same `name` attribute.

If you use the following markup:

```
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="a">
```

then the value will get overridden and you'll just receive the value of the last `<input>` element in your `$_POST` array.

If you want to grab the inputs from multiple `<input>` elements, use the following markup instead:

```
<input type="text" name="a[]">
<input type="text" name="a[]">
<input type="text" name="a[]">
```

In this case, each of the `<input>` elements will be considered separately and you will be able to retrieve the values in the `$_POST` array.

To count the number of occurences of the `<input>` element, you can use the following:

```
echo count($_POST['a']);
```

---

Consider the following code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    print_r($_POST);
    echo count($_POST['a']);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a[]">
    <input type="text" name="a[]">
    <input type="text" name="a[]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This will correctly display the number of `<input>` elements with the `name` attribute equal to `a`.

Comment: and how can i use the elements in the array?

Comment: @ionvoinescu: I thought it was pretty obvious. Like this: `echo $_POST['a'][0];` :)

Comment: well it is not obvious to me because i am new at this and i am trying to learn by example... what i understand from your example is that whatever i input in those input boxes it will be inserted in an array... and the [0] value corresponds to the first element of that array... [1] to the second etc... if i were to retrieve all the elements, i should use `echo $_POST['a'][i];` where i gets a value from 0 to the number of total input boxes right?

Comment: Yes, but using a `foreach` loop is better: `foreach($_POST['a'] as $val) { echo $val; }`

Comment: is there a private chat option here? may i ask help from you with something?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, it will just appear once. The name attribute MUST be unique for all text input fields unless you append square brackets `[]` to the name. Otherwise the last one in the form will overwrite the value from the others.

Answer (score 0):

if you named input name as array a

```
<input type="text" name="a[]">
<input type="text" name="a[]">
<input type="text" name="a[]">
```

then you will get counter as

```
echo count ($_POST['a']);
```

Output: 3

otherwise counter 1