# Dynamically create variables from $_POST fields on a form

Tags: php, post

I'm having trouble creating variables from `$_POST` variables dynamically.

On a form, I have a table where people fill out driver information. The table has one row originally, but if more rows need to be added, the user presses a button, a new row is added, and the field names in the new row increment, i.e: driver1, driver2, driver3, driver4.

I'm trying to get this to match up with my PHP script:

```
$count=1; 

while($count<=100) {
  $driver . string($count) = $_POST['driver . string($count)'];
  $count++;
}
```

Normally I would create a new variable for each `$_POST` variable, but in the case of there being up to 100 rows, I'd like to handle this with a loop.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\host\httpdocs\process.php on line 11
```

Comment: What's your goal here: `$driver . string($count) = $_POST['driver . string($count)'];`?  You have an assignment `= $_POST...` in the middle of a concatenation.

Comment: Ohhh I get it. You're trying to build [variable variables](http://us3.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Why not just keep them in an array? They are, after all, related. They are better organized inside a data structure.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - I foresee a large number of `isset` calls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not reccomended to generate variables programatically. However it is possible:

`${'driver'.$count}`:

```
$count=1; 

while($count<=100) {
  ${'driver'.$count} = $_POST['driver' . $count];
  $count++;
}
```

More about dynamic variables [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

---

I would use arrays to accomplish this though:

```
$driver[$count]=$_POST['driver'.$count];
```

Then you can do

```
foreach ($driver as $count => $postValue){
    // $handling here
}

// OR to access a specific driver
$driver[$count];
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP meant `$_POST['driver' . string($count)]` unless they actually have post fields called `driver . string(42)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

$count=1; 

while($count<=100) {
  ${'driver' . $count} = $_POST['driver' . $count];
  $count++;
}

?>
```

Since $count is a numeric value you don't need to do string cast.

I think this can help you to improve your code [Count the number of times a specific input is present in an form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278640/count-the-number-of-times-a-specific-input-is-present-in-an-form)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [extract](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php) to map each `$_POST` key to a variable of the same name.

```
extract($_POST,EXTR_OVERWRITE,'prefix');
```

This will result in variables named $prefix_driver1, $prefix_driver2... and so on.

(use of prefix is optional, but if you don't use it, a malicious user can manipulate you script variables just by changing the form's input names)